# Windows 11 -- Multiple versions of Python and python in anaconda in one computer-- How do I clean it up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3

Please help. I have multiple problems regarding Python.

Problem 1:
I found python 3.10 inside Inkscape, a graphic program. How do I remove this one? I have Python 3.11 installed elsewhere on this computer. I have no idea which python run when I run python.

Problem 2:
I have multiple python versions 3.9.12, 3.9.13 in Anaconda. I think I have anaconda3 also. I also have python 3.11 installed outside of Anaconda. I like to remove all of the python versions, anaconda versions and start over. How do I do that?

I love python, but I did not know how to manage python. I realize that this is a big mess, so I like to clean it up.